# Finding the index of a string in a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

```
Tup = ('string1','string2','string3')
```

My program returned **string2** how do I get it's index within **Tup**?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
>>> tup.index('string2')
1
```

Note that the `index()` method has only just been added for tuples in versions 2.6 and better.